# How to measure coverage of a libFuzzer fuzzer harness on Android Automotive X86_64 emulator?

Tags: code-coverage, android-source, fuzzing, android-automotive, android-soong

I want to measure the code coverage of the libFuzzer fuzzer harness of the CAN hardware interface that comes with the AOSP, written in C++.

I've attempted to use the Clang flags that allows that and generate a LLVM profile file, but the file is not created. I also found instructions in the Soong docs how to enable that, but still I don't get a profile file.

I'm not sure if there is a problem with the build system or it's just not working in the emulator.